# sendfile() with files (Linux)

Tags: linux, sendfile

I tried this `sendfile` example:
https://github.com/pijewski/sendfile-example/blob/master/sendfile.c

I noticed, I can use `sendfile` with normal files and it works as expected.

I thought, on Linux, it can be used only if destination is network socket?

How it works? Do copy is done with `read` / `write` loop, just inside the kernel.

Comment: Linux is open-source. You can download and look at the source yourself. But most likely it wont be done by a read/write loop. Perhaps some direct memory mapping of buffers?

Comment: The point is, the documentation say it should not be possible...

Comment: "In Linux kernels before 2.6.33, out_fd must refer to a socket. Since Linux 2.6.33 it can be any file.  If it is a regular file, then sendfile() changes the file offset appropriately." https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html